# Error occured because ggplot2 was not upgraded in R 2.15

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need some help with ggplot2. I have got some meteorological data and want to plot the time series. I've tried using a R script it worked for this type of data with light modifications. But when try to ggplot I get an error I've never seen before (not so experienced as R user).

The code I'm using

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

datos=read.csv("dat.txt",header=TRUE,sep=";")
fecha=as.POSIXct(datos[,1], format="%d/%m/%Y")
tmax = ggplot(data=datos,aes(x=fecha, y=TempMax)) + geom_line(colour="red")
```

The error I get when writing `tmax` is

```
Error in cut.default(unclass(x), unclass(breaks), labels = labels, right = right,  : 
  a vector of length 1317420001 could not be assigned
```

Data structure for `dput` can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/s/rkh6db9aqdyfw7k/dputdatos.txt
and original data at https://www.dropbox.com/s/ds5zp9jonznpuwb/dat.txt

Comment: Could you please translate the error message? My spanish (I think it is spanish) is a bit rusty. At first glance it seems that one of your longitude coordinates has a very large value.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it was not translated. Now it is.

Comment: You should have created 'fecha' in the 'datos' dataframe. ggplot methods do not deal well with loose objects. They typically expect the data to be in the same dataframe. (... and avoid the temptation to use 'attach'. It is the work of the Devil.)

Comment: @DWin What do you exactly mean by creating 'fecha' in the 'datos' dataframe?

Comment: `datos$fecha <- as.POSIXct(datos[,1], format="%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: @Dwin No way, it gives the same error message

Comment: Actually, I can't reproduce the error; it runs fine for me on R 2.14.2 and ggplot2 0.9.0.

Comment: @joran I'm using R 2.15.0 (automated update with Ubuntu) and ggplot2 0.8.9

Comment: Ok, then I'd try updating to ggplot2 0.9.0 to see if that fixes things.

Comment: Updated to ggplot2 0.9.0 was the solution. Now it's running fine. Thank you all.

Comment: Given that this is a version issue, I am voting to close as too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from R and ggplot2 versions. I'm using R 2.15.0 and had to update ggplot2 to 0.9.0.

Now everything is running fine.

Thank you all

Comment: When I try it says I have to wait for two days to accept my own answer. I'll do it tomorrow so it can help other users.